# Assign stdout and stderr to a variable when sending output to a file with Subprocess in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, python-2.x, stderr

```
# logging output and errors to file instead of PIPE
# as when the output is over 64K the process can hang for a long time
stdout_file = os.path.join("/var/log/", "migrate_stdout.log")
stderr_file = os.path.join("/var/log/", "migrate_stderr.log")
# append to the file to prevent blowing it away every upgrade
stdout_handle = open(stdout_file, "a")
stderr_handle = open(stderr_file, "a")

migratecmd = "exec /opt/migrate.sh %s %s" % ( body['stadium'], body['version'] )
migrateproc = subprocess.Popen(migratecmd, shell=True, stdout=stdout_handle, stderr=stderr_handle, preexec_fn=self.demote())
result = migrateproc.wait()

if result != 0:
   # stdout,stderr = migrateproc.communicate()
```

Is there a way I can grab `stdout` and `stderr` and assign it to a variable when I am sending data to a file in the example above? The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) suggest that the `.communicate()` tuple will always return `None` but i'm curious to know if there is a workaround (without opening and reading the file). It feels like this could be a common problem.

Comment: If you pass an opened file for the `stdout` or `stderr` channels, then the subprocess will be writing *directly* to the file; the data will not pass through your Python process at all, so there's no possibility of interception.

Comment: @jasonharper That was my understanding. Opening the file and reading from it seemed clunky, which was something I was trying to avoid.